# How to read and parse CSV with react and Papaparse

Tags: reactjs, papaparse

I've been trying to read and parse a CSV file through React and its near impossible for me to find a way it would work.

I would really appreciate the help.

P.S: Thank you in advance for your help.

I'm trying to read a CSV file and then format it with PapaParse. The problem I'm encountering is the actual way I'm trying to achieve this is by the following one

`FetchCSV.js` looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Papa from 'papaparse';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

class DataController extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: []
        };

        this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.getCsvData();
    }

    fetchCsv() {
        return fetch('/data/data.csv').then(function (response) {
            let reader = response.body.getReader();
            let decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');

            return reader.read().then(function (result) {
                return decoder.decode(result.value);
            });
        });
    }

    getData(result) {
        this.setState({data: result.data});
    }

    async getCsvData() {
        let csvData = await this.fetchCsv();

        Papa.parse(csvData, {
            complete: this.getData
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section className="data-controller">
                ...
            </section>
        );
    }
}

export default FetchCSV;
```

I'm getting a problem like this: `no-undef`with `FetchCSV`, I also want to try to get the result on my console but I can't find where to put the `console.log(result);` (which is making things really hard for me). It's also important to mention that I placed this in the `App.js`: `import FetchCSV from "./FetchCSV"` (which I believe is the way it needs to be added).

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is imported name of [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) http library, you should use [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) in order to read and write files, try using fs read.